# how to ignore nmp compile file(.js & .js.map) on AngulaJS project in git

Tags: angularjs, git

in my AngularJS project , we coding with TypeScript, and compiling with NodeJs. now the problem is every time i run npm compile , there are many .js & .js.map file modified on local git repository.  [image]

how to ignore those modified file in git? thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Answer (score 0):

Add following lines in the .gitignore file

```
app/**/*.js
*.js.map
e2e/**/*.js
e2e/**/*.js.map
```

Comment: Praveen,still show modified file on git bash. as Git doc introducing "A gitignore file specifies intentionally untracked files that Git should ignore. Files already tracked by Git are not affected;" currently modified files had tracked by Git. how to resolve this matter?

Comment: @VictorGuan i think this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore